# RTK query stuck at 'loading' state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've a RTK query which returns user information from backend after loggin in. I've also created a slice reducer which takes the payload of RTK query(login call from backend) and stores user information, token in a state(redux-toolkit). Everything  works fine untill I update the state using ExtraReducers.
The RTK query gets Stuck at 'loading' state if I include `state.token= payload.token` , on removing the line, everything works fine(I can access the payload by selecting the 'user' Reducer). I want user token to be stored in user slice so that I can access it in headers and send it back to backend.
Can anybody explain why this is happening?

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authService from "../Services/authService";

const initialState = {
  token: null,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    userLogin: (state, action) => {
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      authService.endpoints.authLogin.matchFulfilled,
      (state, { payload }) => {
        localStorage.setItem("userToken", payload.token);
        state.token = payload.token;
        return payload;
      }
    );
  },
});

export const { userLogin } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that you have an error message on your console that your are ignoring.

In RTK Reducers (or any immerized function in general), you can **either** return a new value, **or** modify `state`. Doing both at once doesn't make any sense.

So you probably want to skip the `return` statement and do

```js
    builder.addMatcher(
      authService.endpoints.authLogin.matchFulfilled,
      (state, { payload }) => {
        localStorage.setItem("userToken", payload.token);
        state.token = payload.token;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar to this GitHub issue: [RTK Query gets stuck pending and swallows errors thrown in addMatcher reducers](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/3795)

There is a bug in where errors don't appear in the console if they're thrown inside a reducer tied to an RTKQ action like `fulfilled`